# How to add TYPE to Object.assign using Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an array of typed objects - all objects are of type: TodoModel. When I filter them, to adjust the content on the UI, you have to create a new array and adjust the properties on the item that was changed for the filter to refilter in angular2. When I create the new array and add the changed object, the object is of no type, while the other 2 objects in the array are still of type: TodoModel. I can't figure out how to assign a type to the new object :( Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is the code for the logic & below I have a screen shot of the before and after for the mutated arrays:

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODO':

        const todo: ITodoModel = payload;

        const i = state.indexOf(todo);

        const status = todo.status == "started" ? "completed" : "started";

        const toggledTodo:ITodoModel = Object.assign(<ITodoModel>{}, todo, {status});

        state = [
            //... = spread operator - bascially loops through the array
            ...state.slice(0,i), // check items before
            toggledTodo, // clicked item
            ...state.slice(i + 1) // check items after
        ];

        console.log('toggle state');
        console.log(state);

return state;
```

[image: Picture of a Before and after array mutation]

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to TodoModel constructor then you can go with something like this:

```
const toggledTodo:ITodoModel = Object.assign(new TodoModel(), todo, {status})
```